# use "this" inside $.each inside object method

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, each

I'm trying to get `this` to point to each `img` inside a function inside an object method, like so

```
var responsiveImageSwap = (function(){
    return {
        init : function(){
            $.each('img', function(){
                var width     = $(window).width(),
                    _this     = this, 
                    alert(_this.attr('src'))
            })
        }
    }
})();
responsiveImageSwap.init();
```

But it is referencing the `object` and not the `img`, how do I reference the image?

Comment: Why not `$('img').each(…`? Also, you *don't* want to compute the viewport width inside a loop.

Comment: ahh good point about width...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This?

```
return {
    init: function () {
        var vw = $(window).width(); // viewport width

        $('img').each(function () {
            var $img = $(this);

            // Do stuff with $img, e.g. retrieve $img.attr('src')
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, you answered the question first with your comment so will accept this (no pun intended)

Answer (score 8):

`$.each` is for looping over collections.  What you are doing is looping over the letters in the string `'img'`.

You want to use `.each`; this is for jQuery objects.

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var width = $(window).width(),
        // this is a DOM element, we need to make it a jQuery object
        _this = $(this), 
     alert(_this.attr('src'))
});
```

Comment: @Virus721: I was just using the code the OP had.  It's not very useful here, but it may be if he uses closures inside the callback.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Your code won't work. `this` refers to the IMG element which does not have a `.attr()` method.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Yeah... I just noticed that. >.<

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I haven't finished my coffee yet, sue me. I fixed it. :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Hehe, I'm drinking my morning coffee right now as well. (The weird part is that it's 4:30 PM where I live.)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I'm in NY, so it's 10:30 AM :)